# MySQL - question marks inserted instead of cyrillic

Tags: mysql

I've read through several time all the previous questions on this and tried everything they suggested, but the issue still persists.

I have a MySQL DB and an second-party app that inserts data into the DB. 
All worked ok until I decided to delete the entire database and create a new empty database by forward engineering a MYSQL model. After the modification, the second-party app began to insert question marks instead of Cyrillic. However, if I try to manually insert Cyrillic, it's ok.

I don't have any access to the source code of second-party app. And - well - even I had, the issue is not in the second-party app, since emphasizing it once more - before deleting and recreating the database, it worked ok.

I tried to do the following:

1)

```
SET GLOBAL character_set_client = 'UTF8';
SET GLOBAL character_set_results = 'UTF8';
SET GLOBAL character_set_server = 'UTF8';
SET GLOBAL character_set_database = 'UTF8'
SET GLOBAL character_set_connection = 'UTF8'
```

2)

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_of_interest_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

After all of the modification, I tried to restart apache. Just in case.
What am I missing ?!! Help me please

Comment: Maybe you encode your data multiple times? You can try dumping it and importing it again

Comment: I've tried to do it. I've deleted the db on the remote server, and imported it again

Answer (score 0):

What have done is set the default. You need to chance the collation of the columns too

ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY
    col1 VARCHAR(5)
      CHARACTER SET latin1
      COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci

From the docs

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html

Comment: No. It didn't help. I've tried ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: And I can't see why should I modify a single column. My DB has hundreds of tables

Comment: You shouldn't have to in the future. The columns inherit from the defaults when the table is created.